# convert smile bbcode to html tag

Tags: php

i would convert bbcode smiley to html tag.

For convert i fid this code :

```
function showBBcodes($text) {
// BBcode array
$find = array(
'~\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]~s',
'~\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]~s',
'~\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]~s',
'~\[del\](.*?)\[/del\]~s',
'~\[a\](.*?)\[/a\]~s',
'~\[quote\](.*?)\[/quote\]~s',
'~\[size=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/size\]~s',
'~\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/color\]~s',
'~\[resim\](.*?)\[/resim\]~s',
'~\[font=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/font\]~s',
);
// HTML tags to replace BBcode
$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<i>$1</i>',
'<span style="text-decoration:underline;">$1</span>',
'<del>$1</del>',
'<a href="$1">$1</a>',
'<pre>$1</'.'pre>',
'<span style="font-size:$1px;">$2</span>',
'<span style="color:$1;">$2</span>',
'<img src="$1">',
'<p style="font-family:$1">$2</p>',
);
// Replacing the BBcodes with corresponding HTML tags
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$text);
}
// How to use the above function:
$bbtext = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "dtext");
$htmltext = showBBcodes($bbtext);
echo $htmltext;
```

As you see first it find after change. Smile bbcode :

```
[:)] -> smile
[:|] -> shy
[:(] -> fury
[:o] -> swanky
[;)] -> blinking
```

Photos :

[image: smile] [image: shy] [image: fury] [image: swanky] [image: blinking]

How show the smiles in array find and replace?

I need your help.

Not : I don't have a good English.

Comment: Please, could you insert the image(s) here? I can't see them. Thank you.

Comment: @Syscall i edited the question

Comment: Can't you just call `$text = str_replace(['[:)]', '[:|]'], ['<img src="...">', '<img src="...">'], $text);`?

Comment: @Syscall thanks you i resolved

Comment: Elegant........